# Ajax is not able to call the controller method

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor-pages

My jQuery on click function is working but ajax is not calling the controller method. From what I have found so far is that usually url routing is the issue but even after correcting the issue ther ajax is still not working. Is there something else I am missing?

Form

```
                <form id="languageCreateForm">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="recipient-name" class="col-form-label">Category Name</label>
                        <input name="@createlanguage.Name" type="text" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group text-center">
                        <input id="languagePostButton"  type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" />
                    </div>
                </form>
```

jQuery

```
$('#languagePostButton').on("click", function () {
    var data = $("#languageCreateForm").serialize();
    $.ajax(
        {
            type: 'POST', 
            url: 'languages/CreateAjx',
            dataType: "text";
            data: data,
            success: function () {
                alert("language create fired");
            }
        });

});
```

Controller

```
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async  Task<JsonResult> CreateAjx(language language)
        {
            var result = false;


            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _context.Add(language);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                result = true;
            }
            return Json(result);

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a `ValidateAntiForgeryToken` attribute on the Action method. But you don't appear to be generating or passing a token. Add

```
 @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
```

within the form element. Then the generated hidden field will be included in the AJAX post.

You also need to prevent the default action of the submit button:

```
$('#languagePostButton').on("click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var data = $("#languageCreateForm").serialize();
    $.ajax(
        {
            type: 'POST', 
            url: 'languages/CreateAjx',
            dataType: "text";
            data: data,
            success: function () {
                alert("language create fired");
            }
        });

});
```

Comment: Thanks Mike! Always forget about .preventdefault().